# Google Web sign throws 400 error out of the blue

Tags: google-signin

Google Web Sign (JS) suddenly stopped working in our products today - out of the blue with a **400 error** with the following error message:
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Parameter not allowed for this message type: prompt"
}

We traced the breakage to the "prompt" sign in option config. In the following code, as soon as commented out the prompt config, it worked.

```
gapi.client.init({
                    client_id: clientId,
                    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                    prompt:"select_account",//commenting this code out stopped the breakage
                    discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
                    scope: SCOPES.join(" "),

                }).then(function () {
                    //we do something with it
                });
```

Screenshot: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAK5kGGdJp9EkJC0lafcuREnLrNFt-u5muY

This was previously working code, the "prompt" parameter is still supported as per the documentation ([see here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsigninoptions)).

This bug proved enormously expensive for us as we are in the middle of a campaign with lot of users attempting to register for the first time with our product.